# notepad-plus-plus snap does not start on Ubuntu

Tags: snap

I created this question on stackoverflow and it was downvoted. I hope this is right comunity to ask.

I installed notepad-plus-plus on Ubuntu 16.04 machine. It was working fine. With no evident reason it stopped to work. Icon disappeared from application list. When I launch shell script /snap/notepad-plus-plus/current/bin/notepad-plus-plus I get error message:

> You need to connect this snap to the wine-platform-i386 snap.
>
> snap connect :wine-platform-plug wine-platform-i386:wine-base-stable

I removed snapd (sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd) and installed it again. Same behavior.
I installed notepad-plus-plus snap on another Ubuntu system and it works fine.

How to 'connect' notepad-plus-plus snap to the wine-platform-i386 snap?

System info:

`~$ snap --version
snap    2.35.4
snapd   2.35.4
series  16
ubuntu  16.04
kernel  4.10.0-14-lowlatency`

`~$ snap list
Name                Version    Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core                16-2.35.4  5662  stable    canonical✓  core
notepad-plus-plus   7.5.9      124   stable    mmtrt       -
wine-platform-i386  1.0        23    stable    mmtrt       -`

Update:

`snap interfaces | grep notepad-plus-plus
:desktop                              notepad-plus-plus
:desktop-legacy                       notepad-plus-plus
:home                                 notepad-plus-plus
:network                              notepad-plus-plus
:opengl                               notepad-plus-plus
:wayland                              notepad-plus-plus
:x11                                  notepad-plus-plus
wine-platform-i386:wine-base-stable   notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug
-                                     notepad-plus-plus:cups-control
-                                     notepad-plus-plus:hardware-observe
-                                     notepad-plus-plus:process-control
-                                     notepad-plus-plus:removable-media`

Update 2:

`snap interfaces wine-platform-i386
Slot                                  Plug
wine-platform-i386:wine-base-devel    -
wine-platform-i386:wine-base-stable   notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug
wine-platform-i386:wine-base-staging  -`

Comment: What are the results of `snap interfaces | grep notepad-plus-plus` ?

Comment: `
:desktop                              npp
:desktop-legacy                       npp
:home                                 npp
:network                              npp
:opengl                               npp
:wayland                              npp
:x11                                  npp
wine-platform-i386:wine-base-stable   npp:wine-platform-plug
-                                    npp:cups-control
-                                    npp:hardware-observe
-                                    npp:process-control
-                                    npp:removable-media
`

Comment: Please note: I replaced text notepad-plus-plus with npp since comment was too long
`:desktop npp`

`:desktop-legacy npp`
`:home npp`
`:network npp`
`:opengl npp`
`:wayland npp`
`:x11 npp`
`wine-platform-i386:wine-base-stable npp:wine-platform-plug`
`- npp:cups-control`
`- npp:hardware-observe`
`- npp:process-control`
`- npp:removable-media`

Comment: What are the results of `snap interfaces wine-platform-i386`? Are there any plugs listed under the `Plug` column or are there nothing but `-` characters which means no plugs are listed?

Comment: I updated question with output of 'snap interfaces wine-platform-i386'. Out of curiosity: I do not find much information about commands @karel is asking. I follow blindly instruction without knowing what I am doing and why. It would be nice if I would understand background of those commands. Any good source of information? (Google search did not help much. It seems my questions are not properly defined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your command-output the plug `notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug` is connected to the slot `wine-platform-i386:wine-base-stable` already. But the mandatory plug `notepad-plus-plus:process-control` is not connected.

You need to run

```
sudo snap connect notepad-plus-plus:process-control
```

Source:
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/call-for-testing-notepad-plus-plus/4498

Comment: I followed your instruction and run `sudo snap connect notepad-plus-plus:process-control`. After it, I tried to run shell script `/snap/notepad-plus-plus/current/bin/notepad-plus-plus`. I got same error: `You need to connect this snap to the wine-platform-i386 snap.` I did not runn commands you specified in second answer but tried directly `snap run notepad-plus-plus` and notepad-plus-plus started after soem initialization time. I will keep reference to your answer two and refer to it if I experience problem. Thank you for link. I got some understanding of snap.

Comment: Notepad-plus-plus started with warning `error: Z:\home\i055150\snap\notepad-plus-plus\124\notepad-plus-plus\plugins\Config\Hunspell\en_US.usr: cannot open`. I checked and file does not exist. I created empty file and restarted notepad-plus-plus and no warning.