# Notepad++ snap package doesn't launch

Tags: 18.04, wine, snap

I installed the Notepad++ snap package few months ago in Ubuntu 18.04, and it worked perfectly.
Two weeks ago suddenly Notepad++ stopped opening. When I click on the Notepad++ icon nothing happens. I removed and installed Notepad++ again, but it's still not working. I haven't any logs about this.

When I run `snap run notepad-plus-plus` I get the following results:

```
wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string, error message   
"wine: WINEARCH set to win64 but '/home/my-username/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine'  
is a 32-bit installation."
```

Comment: **This question is not a duplicate of any other existing question.** including [notepad-plus-plus snap does not start on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087032/notepad-plus-plus-snap-does-not-start-on-ubuntu). They are completely different issues and only Taqi Reza's answer which has also been accepted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094439/unable-to-use-or-open-notepad-after-installation/1094771#1094771) solves this issue.

Answer (score 9):

That issue is due to big changes made to the snap. This is now using 64bit version of `Notepad++` with `wine64` on `amd64` systems and `32bit` version of Notepad++ on `i386` systems. This snap is now using `wine-platform` snap so this has both `i386 & amd64` wine pkgs earlier it was using `wine-platform-i386` snap which only had wine `i386` pkgs. So currently migrating to `wine-platform` snap from older `wine-platform-i386` snap which is not done automatically when user updates the snap caused issue. I'm currently pushing changes to detect if user is still connected snap on older platform should ask to do these commands.

Run these commands will fix your issue.

- `snap disconnect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug`
- `snap install wine-platform`
- `snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug wine-platform:wine-base-stable`

If issue still exists then you have to remove win32 `WINEPREFIX` in order to create win64.

- `rm -r $HOME/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine`

Comment: did you tried running three commands I posted.

Comment: Alright, can you post info of `snap interfaces notepad-plus-plus` also can you tell which `arch' of Ubuntu you are running.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit. [Results of `snap interfaces notepad-plus-plus`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MFrDqyCM4n/)

Comment: you are still connected to `wine-platform-i386:wine-base-stable` which is the problem so try to follow the solution I have posted already ok try to run these one by one `snap disconnect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug`

`snap install wine-platform`

`snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug wine-platform:wine-base-stable`

Comment: +1 The commands in your previous comment worked!