# Unable to use or open Notepad++ after installation

Tags: 18.04, snap

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. I tried installing Notepad++ using the following commands:

```
sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
```

However, after installing it, I can see Notepad ++ is installed but I am unable to open it.

When I run `snap run notepad-plus-plus` I get the following results:

```
wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string, error message   
"wine: WINEARCH set to win64 but '/home/my-username/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine'  
is a 32-bit installation."
```

I also tried the suggestion mentioned in

[notepad-plus-plus snap does not start on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087032/notepad-plus-plus-snap-does-not-start-on-ubuntu)

but can't get Notepad ++ to open.

Comment: @N0rbert the link does not seem to solve the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That issue is due to big changes made to the snap. This is now using 64bit version of `Notepad++` with `wine64` on `amd64` systems and `32bit` version of Notepad++ on `i386` systems. This snap is now using `wine-platform` snap so this has both `i386 & amd64` wine pkgs earlier it was using `wine-platform-i386` snap which only had wine `i386` pkgs. So currently migrating to `wine-platform` snap from older `wine-platform-i386` snap which is not done automatically when user updates the snap caused issue. I'm currently pushing changes to detect if user is still connected snap on older platform should ask to do these commands.

Run these commands will fix your issue.

- `snap disconnect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug`
- `snap install wine-platform`
- `snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug wine-platform:wine-base-stable`

If issue still exists then you have to remove win32 `WINEPREFIX` in order to create win64.

- `rm -r $HOME/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine`

Comment: It seems that I can add any comment. 

I tried using `snap disconnect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug` but it gives me the following error: 

error: snap "notepad-plus-plus" has no plug or slot named "wine-platform-plug"

The command `snap install wine-platform` and does the due to installation. 

However, `snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug wine-platform:wine-base-stable`

gives an error message: snap connect notepad-plus-plus:wine-platform-plug wine-platform:wine-base-stable

Comment: I haven't tried `rm -r $HOME/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine`.Since I am new to Linux, can you please be more elaborate?

Comment: @user3571389 I tried this answer on my Ubuntu 18.04 and it worked without needing to run `rm -r $HOME/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine`. All I needed to do to fix the problem with Notepad++ not opening was to run the first three bullet point commands from this answer, one after another.

Comment: @karel not sure what I have done but it seems to be working now.

Comment: But my Notepad showing message "Updating wine..." after I am executing `rm -r $HOME/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine` and then still can't open file. Without this command file can't be opened too. How can I fix it?

Comment: @nick try to start npp from terminal, snap run notepad-plus-plus see if any error on log.

Comment: I had earlier opened, however had issue, now *** `rm -r`  deleted all my previously opened [unsaved] files***

Comment: error: cannot find current revision for snap notepad-plus-plus: readlink /snap/notepad-plus-plus/current: no such file or directory

Comment: I am also getting this @saiid